# leaflet / change a geojson divicon html

Tags: leaflet, geojson, json

I have a geojson layer with a divIcon and now i want to change it. i have tried whit seticon but it does not work. How could i do it?

This is what I am trying:

```
papesjson.eachLayer(function(layer){
    if (layer.feature.properties.estado == "BAJA"){
        awesomeclase ="fa-circle-o-notch";
    }
    else if (layer.feature.properties.estado == "PENDIENTE REPOSICION"){
        awesomeclase = "fa-plus";
    }
    else if (layer.feature.properties.estado == "RETIRADA"){
        awesomeclase = "fa-times";
    }
    else {
        awesomeclase = "fa-circle";
    }
    var myIcon = L.divIcon({ 
        iconSize: new L.Point(50, 50), 
        //iconAnchor:[50, 50],
        className: "divicon",
        html:'<i id = "'+layer.feature.properties.codigo+'" class="fa ' + awesomeclase + '" style="color:'+ getColor(layer.feature.properties.modelo) + ';">'
    });

    layer.setIcon(myIcon);
});
```

Comment: could it be because the html snipplet is not valid? you open the `<i>` but don't close it …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, finally i found out that i wouldn´t update the properties of my geojson. Everything is working now!

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this fits your use case, but you might be able to use `pointToLayer` when constructing the geojson

```
var papesjson = L.geoJson(someGeojson, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {

        if (feature.properties.estado == "BAJA"){
            awesomeclase ="fa-circle-o-notch";
        }
        else if (feature.properties.estado == "PENDIENTE REPOSICION"){
            awesomeclase = "fa-plus";
        }
        else if (feature.properties.estado == "RETIRADA"){
            awesomeclase = "fa-times";
        }
        else {
            awesomeclase = "fa-circle";
        }
        var myIcon = L.divIcon({ 
            iconSize: new L.Point(50, 50), 
            //iconAnchor:[50, 50],
            className: "divicon",
            html:'<i id = "'+feature.properties.codigo+'" class="fa ' + awesomeclase + '" style="color:'+ getColor(feature.properties.modelo) + ';">'
        });

        return L.marker(latlng, {icon: myIcon});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already do that to create papesjson. My goal is to redraw all points without add the layer again

Comment: you might consider adding the markers to a layerGroup when parsing from the geojson. Instead of using a geojson layer. My sense is that the markers will be easier to access/change from layerGroup.